# Angular material autocomplete component displays options on the footer instead of the header

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular9

I created an angular component for my navbar which I want to implement a search function with autocomplete, I linked my backend and created services and it retrieves data perfectly, But the problem is it displays the retrieved data on the footer!!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mynavbar">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link nav-link-r" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link nav-link-r" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-r" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 <div> 

  <!-- simple autocomplete component from material.angular.io -->
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="Pick one"
             aria-label="Number"
             matInput
             [formControl]="myControl"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>  
</div>
</nav>
```

the navbar is a template from bootstrap and the only additional CSS styles in this component are the following

```
.mynavbar{
background-color: #6EB06B !important;
}
.nav-link-r{
color: white !important;
font-size: large;
}
.autofill-space{
overflow: visible !important;
}
.option-items{
color: tomato;
 }
.example-form {
min-width: 150px;
max-width: 500px;
width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
width: 100%;
}
```

I want the retrieved options to be displayed under the text input like in the original component but this keeps displaying it in the footer area skipping the entire website body, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your form field looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of is that there are material styles missing from your build. Did you include the material styles: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: I guess so, I ran a add @angular/material, imported MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatAutocompleteModule in app.module.ts, and also imported FormControl in my component.ts. did I miss a step?

Comment: this is the guide I followed https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-autocomplete-tutorial-with-angular-material/

Comment: oh shit I'm so sorry, I'm sorry I got confused on which of my questions I'm answering XD, this actually was a material import issue, however even after i fixed it it left me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955281/how-to-make-angular-material-component-appear-on-top-the-navbar